# Ruby Version required 2.4.1 for windows

Tags: ruby

I am looking for an migration from assembla to jira, For this i need Ruby version 2.4.1(windows exe file) but i am unable to find it anywhere still now . can anyone share me the link. so, i will be able to complete my task.

Comment: Search engine turned up nothing? If you need Ruby 2.4 then it's likely any version of 2.4 will suffice since Ruby uses semantic versioning.

Comment: @vinodhA : I am running Ruby  2.6.4 which comes with Cygwin.

Comment: After a quick google search you can find [the ruby-lang page](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/22/ruby-2-4-1-released/) and [the rubyinstaller page](https://rubyinstaller.org/2017/07/04/rubyinstaller-2.4.1-2-released.html). Still, it would be ideal if you use a version manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/ and download the version you want.

These are specifically for Windows users.

Looks like the v2.4.1 exe is https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/2.4.1-2/rubyinstaller-2.4.1-2-x64.7z

But if you’re OK with v2.4.10 - and I’d highly recommend that you try it, it will have security and big fixes which 2.4.1 lacks and will likely be compatible with anything which requires 2.4.x - then download this exe https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/RubyInstaller-2.4.10-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.10-1-x64.exe which includes the basic gems you’ll also need.

Comment: The version hardcoded for my migration is 2.4.1, because of that i am not able to use other version, if some can help me by running a ruby it would be greatful

Comment: The link for 2.4.1 is also in my answer. https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/2.4.1-2/rubyinstaller-2.4.1-2-x64.7z